# Meteor with Semantic UI dropdown behavior not working

Tags: jquery, meteor, semantic-ui

I am currently trying to integrate Semantic UI into my app. The visual styling is displaying fine. However, behaviors do not appear to be working and I am not able to raise any form of exceptions in my console to help with debugging.

- I created a Meteor test app at https://github.com/andersr/semantic-test
- I do not see any exceptions in the console and am not sure how to troubleshoot this. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Some relevant code snippets:

Markup for a user nav dropdown:

`<div class="ui dropdown link item">
     {{currentUser.name}}
      <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
      <div class="menu">
          <a class="item">Sign Out</a>
       </div>
    </div>`

custom.semantic.json file:

```
{
  "definitions": {
  ...
  "dropdown": true,
  ...
 }
```

}

Invoking the dropdown in /client/client.js (though not sure if this is needed):

```
$('.dropdown').dropdown({
  transition: 'drop'
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`jQuery` plugins need to be initalized when the corresponding HTML elements have been inserted in the DOM, which is usually the case in standard server side rendered webapps, but Meteor takes a different approach by using client side reactive templating, all the HTML generation is done in the browser.

This is why you need to initialize `jQuery` plugins when Meteor has done inserting your dropdown in the document, you can use the template `onRendered` lifecycle event to detect when you can safely activate the widget behavior.

JS

```
Template.dropdown.onRendered(function(){
  this.$(".dropdown").dropdown();
});
```

HTML

```
<template name="dropdown">
  <div class="ui dropdown link item">
    {{currentUser.name}} <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
    <div class="menu">
      <a class="item">Sign Out</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: That fixed it.  Thanks!  (And I will now submit a request to the maintainers of https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-Meteor/ to consider mentioning the need for including this in their ReadMe docs.)